# Tautological and normal bundles over flag manifolds and jet bundles

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, grassmannians, flags, jets

Hello! Recently, doing my research on jet bundles, I was led to consider the following construction.

---

Let $V$ be a real vector space of dimension $n$. Consider the flag manifold $G(V,k,l)$ and the two Grassmann manifolds $G(V,k)$ and $G(V,l)$. It seems to me that there are two natural projections $\eta:G(V,k,l)\to G(V,k)$ and $\pi:G(V,k,l)\to G(V,l)$. If I'm not mistaken, $\eta^{-1}(K)=G(K,l)$ and $\pi^{-1}(L)=G((V/L)^*,k-l)$. Now each Grassmann manifold is accompanied by its own tautological bundle, and I can use the above projections to lift the tautological bundles over $G(V,k,l)$. Namely, let $\Theta$ (resp., $\theta$) the tautological bundle over $G(V,k)$ (resp., over  $G(V,l)$), and consider their pullbacks $\overline{\Theta}:=\eta^\ast(\Theta)$ and $\overline{\theta}:=\pi^\ast(\theta)$. By definition, the $\overline{\Theta}$-fiber over a point $(K,L)\in G(V,k,l)$ is $K$, while the $\overline{\theta}$-fiber over the same point is $L$. Hence, I can obtain a "normal tautological bundle" $\nu:=\overline{\Theta}/\overline{\theta}$ of rank $k-l$.

> QUESTION A
>
> - Is the bundle $\nu$ I've just described a well-known construction?
>     If yes, where I can find it?
> - In the case of a complete flag manifolds, we would have an $n$--tuple
>     of line bundles. Does it have any
>     special interpretation?

---

Now let $\pi:E\to M$ a smooth vector bundle of smooth manifolds, of rank $n$. It seems natural to associate to $\pi$ a smooth bundle $G(\pi,k,l)$ by replacing each fiber with its flag (or, in particular, Grassmann) manifold. In its turn,  $G(\pi,k,l)$ is the base of vector bundles of tautological type (constructed, fiber by fiber, just as above). I'm aware of a case when this construction is of some use: $G(\tau_M,k)$ is the 1-st jet bundle $J^1(M,k)$ over the $k$--dimensional manifold $M$ ($\tau_M$ being the tangent bundle); the corresponding tautological $k$-dimensional bundle over  $J^1(M,k)$ is by some authors called the $R$-distribution, and it plays a key role in defining higher order jet spaces and the Cartan distribution over them.

> QUESTION B
>
> - Is the construction of "flag bundles" out of vector ones a
>     well-known one? If yes, are their
>     properties (e.g., behavior w.r.t.
>     bundle morphisms) examined somewhere?
> - Does exist an analogous construction of jet spaces, carried
>     out by using the "flag bundles" of the
>     tangent bundle, instead of the
>     Grassmann bundles? If yes, does the
>     "normal tautological bundle" (describe
>     above) play any relevant role in such
>     a theory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is "yes." I'm not sure about the jet bundle stuff (not really my area), but everything else you've written is extremely well-known stuff in Lie theory.  I've used them dozens of times in my own work.  The quotient bundles you're calling "normal tautological bundle" i would just call "tautological bundle." In fact, it's well known enough that it's hard for me to give a reference, though you can try these [notes of Brion](http://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/~mbrion/lecturesrev.pdf) or chapter 10 of Fulton's Young Tableaux (thought these are both for complex manifolds, not real ones; perhaps someone who knows the real theory better can help me with a reference).  The line bundles on the flag variety indeed play an important role: they generate the Picard group of the variety and their Chern classes generate the cohomology, with all the relations in cohomology manifest from the fact that these filter a trivial bundle. They are also a special class of the line bundles that come up in discussions of Borel-Weil attached to weights of SL(n); these are ones attached to the weights which appear in the vector representation.

The notion of "flag bundles" you mention is also standard: you just quotient the frame bundle by upper-triangular matrices. This often comes up in discussion of the [splitting principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splitting_principle).

Comment: @Ben: thanks for the highlights on the Picard group and the splitting principle! Thanks also for the references - though I'm still looking for the construction in the real case. I knew it's a trivial fact, but this make it harder to find a reference.
Still waiting for some hints about my questions on jet bundles...